# matlab: variable horizontal alignment of text

Tags: matlab, text

Text objects in MATLAB contain a horizontal alignment property, which can be assigned a value of left, center, or right. Attempts to assign this property by a vector of alignments of equal length to the vectors of strings and coordinates fails to give the intended behavior.

For instance, a statement of the form :

```
text([1,1,1]/4,[1,2,3]/4,{'ABC';'BCD';'CDE'})
```

displays the contents of a length-3 cell array of char objects at the X- and Y-coordinates specified by length-3 double arrays. However, attempting to introduce a length-3 cell array of char objects for independent specification of the horizontal alignment of each text element is syntactically invalid;

e.g.,

```
text([1,1,1]/4,[1,2,3]/4,{'ABC';'BCD';'CDE'},'HorizontalAlignment',{'left';'center';'right'})
```

My question concerns whether it is possible to specify the **HorizontalAlignment** property of MATLAB text objects in a variable manner without resorting to constructs explicitly involving loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign multiple property values upon creation, but once you have a vector of handles, you can use the many-to-many form of [`set()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/set.html) like so:

```
h = text([1,1,1]/4, [1,2,3]/4, {'ABC';'BCD';'CDE'});
set(h, {'HorizontalAlignment'}, {'left';'center';'right'});
```

The value array has one row per object, one column per property.